# Storing data into URL links?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find out the keyword I'm looking for. When I google anything with URL encoding or storing data, include data, whatever, I get all kinds of results except what I'm interested in. This is the only website I could find off the top of my head that shows what I'm looking for:

http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree/AAAAAgMA37CCEEGWBUKusyycwbTk7HYRfq9JsgLjB6Vr230Y7IpzU8BU5oERUDGIeQMI9It6EHQOXEV-Va6X9JeVUlOPpkSrPV8EB0yzLR-NGeAS3Yy1heZM2V8ucA==

after tree/ it has a long code that pretty much is full of data. What should I look into to be able to do something like that? Is one supposed to create their own method according to what they need? Or is there a way one can just take one super long text and have a library encode it to make it smaller for the URL and then decode it when it loads?

I require tons of numbers, around 100. I figured it would be something like this, first off use a symbol to separate each 'variable', in this case let's use '-' and do something like this:

`www.url.com/tree/1-1-1-0-3-2-1-3-4-5-2...total of 100 numbers..1-0-2`, but then it gets encoded to be much smaller to something like
`www.url.com/tree/xDgdmFdmnDfjSDfjSFdKflWepLS` and this url gets decoded once loaded and the data retrieved and used behind the scenes.

Is there an *easier* way of doing this, or does one have to do it manually depending on their needs? By easier I mean, a way of encoding it, or does one have to do the encoding themselves? For example, make it so if there are more of the same numbers next to each other then it takes them and transforms them into letters, let's say there are five 3's next to each other, it would use the letter c to show what the number is, and a capital letter for the number of times it's repeated, so cE would mean five 3's in a row.

My question is, is there a way to encode it or do I have to think of a way to encode it myself like I was writing in the example?

Any information you have related to this subjecte is GREATLY appreciated!! Thanks so much in advance for taking the time to read all this and reply, sorry to bother

Comment: That's Base64 encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 It transforms any byte array into a transmittable text. Especially if you use the web-safe version of it.

Comment: Dang, would have never guessed that name, thanks so much. and thanks a bunch of the link!

Comment: Remember: If you see a gibberish string of letters and numbers ending in one or two `=` signs, you can immediately impress everyone by going "I know that! That's Base64!" ;-)

Comment: Hehe. Wow I'm so glad there's an easy way to encode it. I was worried I'd have to put a lot of time in doing it manually, I love you guys. Thanks so much once again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to base 64 encode data.